# How to add service to run at boot on slackware linux?

Tags: services, slackware, autostart

I am trying a Slackware 14.2. I can start sshd by `/etc/rc.d/rc.inet1 sshd start` but my question is how to add service to run at boot on slackware linux? Basically how to permanently add services to system on Slackware Linux and also check that service status. So far I am able to achieve the above using this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1286734/slackware-services-and-runlevels),

```
$ sudo nano /etc/rc.d/rc.M
```

and adding these lines

```
# Start the sshd server
if [ -x /etc/rc.d/rc.sshd ]; then
  . /etc/rc.d/rc.sshd
fi
```

and it did work and ssh server started automatically after boot as I was able to ssh to that system but how to check that service status within the system other than `ps aux | grep ssh` or `netstat -lntp | grep ssh` or using tools like `lsof`? What I meant is some thing usual way like `sudo service sshd status` or `sudo systemctl status sshd` .

Comment: Oops! I should have known that ***systemd*** and ***openrc/init*** walks through their separate paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slackware use the BSD-style init system. `sshd` daemon is handled on boot with `rc.inet2` script and is handled on shutdown with `rc.0` and `rc.6` on reboot.

To start `sshd` daemon on boot add execute permission to `rc.sshd` script:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.sshd
```

To disable `sshd` on boot remove execute permission:

```
chmod -x /etc/rc.d/rc.sshd
```

In alternative you can manage `sshd` daemon (stop&start and restart) using the rc script:

```
sh /etc/rc.d/rc.sshd
usage /etc/rc.d/rc.sshd start|stop|restart
```

Comment: Cool, just one more thing to complete the answer, how to check that service status? And that will make the answer eligible to be accepted.

Comment: The `rc.sshd` script dont' provide a facility to check SSH server status. Other `rc` script provide the `status` argument for checking the service status:
`
    # sh /etc/rc.d/rc.docker status
    Status of dockerd: running
`

Comment: yeah, that's why I accepted the answer without it :)

Answer (score 2):

> Any services or daemons that use the network should be started from
>   [`/etc/rc.d/rc.inet2`]. Most of the rc scripts in charge of starting daemons like inetd, sshd, bind, nfs, etc get called from `rc.inet2`. - Source http://www.slackware.com/config/network.php